# Ignition.start() get stuck with warning "Still waiting for initial partition map exchange"

Tags: java, apache-spark, ignite

When we try to start ignite grid , it gets stuck. While it was stuck i have observed that below warning comes in log:

```
WARN  9981874     90     2019-11-22 23:52:35     org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi     exchange-worker-#658%ReplicatedGrid_application_1571067740090_0645_1%     Failed to connect shared memory endpoint to port (is shared memory server endpoint up and running?): 48100
WARN  9981874     90     2019-11-22 23:53:05     org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCachePartitionExchangeManager     Executor task launch worker-2     Failed to wait for initial partition map exchange. Possible reasons are:
  ^-- Transactions in deadlock.
  ^-- Long running transactions (ignore if this is the case).
  ^-- Unreleased explicit locks.

After that it starts writing below warning continuously :

WARN  9981874     90     2019-11-22 23:53:35     org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCachePartitionExchangeManager     Executor task launch worker-2     Still waiting for initial partition map exchange [fut=GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture [dummy=false, forcePreload=false, reassign=false, discoEvt=DiscoveryEvent [evtNode=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=c54ef27b-049e-466e-a594-3fffb01bd1e3, addrs=[10.141.180.69, 10.141.26.13, 10.142.225.122, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=[/10.141.26.13:47512, /127.0.0.1:47512, nvmbd2bgt130d00.rjil.ril.com/10.141.180.69:47512, /10.142.225.122:47512], discPort=47512, order=14, intOrder=9, lastExchangeTime=1574447015048, loc=true, ver=1.7.0#20160801-sha1:383273e3, isClient=false], topVer=14, nodeId8=c54ef27b, msg=null, type=NODE_JOINED, tstamp=1574446951740], crd=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=81757f48-d3e7-466d-9058-8edc84496f4f, addrs=[10.141.180.69, 10.141.26.13, 10.142.225.122, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=[/127.0.0.1:47511, /10.141.26.13:47511, nvmbd2bgt130d00.rjil.ril.com/10.141.180.69:47511, /10.142.225.122:47511], discPort=47511, order=1, intOrder=1, lastExchangeTime=1574446951670, loc=false, ver=1.7.0#20160801-sha1:383273e3, isClient=false], exchId=GridDhtPartitionExchangeId [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=14, minorTopVer=0], nodeId=c54ef27b, evt=NODE_JOINED], added=false, initFut=GridFutureAdapter [resFlag=0, res=null, startTime=1574446955042, endTime=0, ignoreInterrupts=false, state=INIT], init=false, topSnapshot=null, lastVer=null, partReleaseFut=null, affChangeMsg=null, skipPreload=false, clientOnlyExchange=false, initTs=1574446955052, centralizedAff=false, evtLatch=0, remaining=[88ed2a8c-c0b5-4b93-b3e4-529d00d5b118, 81757f48-d3e7-466d-9058-8edc84496f4f, 6727f535-2e69-4520-a1e0-8b2a2380134d], srvNodes=[TcpDiscoveryNode [id=81757f48-d3e7-466d-9058-8edc84496f4f, addrs=[10.141.180.69, 10.141.26.13, 10.142.225.122, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=[/127.0.0.1:47511, /10.141.26.13:47511, nvmbd2bgt130d00.rjil.ril.com/10.141.180.69:47511, /10.142.225.122:47511], discPort=47511, order=1, intOrder=1, lastExchangeTime=1574446951670, loc=false, ver=1.7.0#20160801-sha1:383273e3, isClient=false], TcpDiscoveryNode [id=6727f535-2e69-4520-a1e0-8b2a2380134d, addrs=[10.141.180.69, 10.141.26.13, 10.142.225.122, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=[/10.142.225.122:47515, /127.0.0.1:47515, /10.141.26.13:47515, nvmbd2bgt130d00.rjil.ril.com/10.141.180.69:47515], discPort=47515, order=5, intOrder=4, lastExchangeTime=1574446951670, loc=false, ver=1.7.0#20160801-sha1:383273e3, isClient=false], TcpDiscoveryNode [id=88ed2a8c-c0b5-4b93-b3e4-529d00d5b118, addrs=[10.141.180.69, 10.141.26.13, 10.142.225.122, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=[/10.142.225.122:47516, /10.141.26.13:47516, /127.0.0.1:47516, nvmbd2bgt130d00.rjil.ril.com/10.141.180.69:47516], discPort=47516, order=8, intOrder=6, lastExchangeTime=1574446951670, loc=false, ver=1.7.0#20160801-sha1:383273e3, isClient=false], TcpDiscoveryNode [id=c54ef27b-049e-466e-a594-3fffb01bd1e3, addrs=[10.141.180.69, 10.141.26.13, 10.142.225.122, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=[/10.141.26.13:47512, /127.0.0.1:47512, nvmbd2bgt130d00.rjil.ril.com/10.141.180.69:47512, /10.142.225.122:47512], discPort=47512, order=14, intOrder=9, lastExchangeTime=1574447015048, loc=true, ver=1.7.0#20160801-sha1:383273e3, isClient=false]], super=GridFutureAdapter [resFlag=0, res=null, startTime=1574446955042, endTime=0, ignoreInterrupts=false, state=INIT]]]
```

The above warning may go for 15 hours and we have to restart the ignite server. Sometimes it works fine.
I tried searching on google and did not find any relevant answer. Please help understand the issue.
Thanks.

Also i have observed that there are many nodes on the same machine with same IP address but different port.

```
Below is the logs where we can see this:

 - :19/11/18 18:46:00 WARN GridCachePartitionExchangeManager: Still
   waiting for initial partition map exchange
   [fut=GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture [dummy=false,
   forcePreload=false, reassign=false, discoEvt=DiscoveryEvent
   [evtNode=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=3e9e1886-6e9c-491c-8145-e73c3f46ce8b,
   addrs=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo, 10.141.173.24, 10.141.180.83,
   10.142.225.62, 127.0.0.1, 2405:200:a60:f9f1:1602:ecff:fe68:f381%bond2],
   sockAddrs=[/10.142.225.62:47520, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo:47520,
   /127.0.0.1:47520, rocraappsl11.rjil.ril.com/10.141.180.83:47520,
   /2405:200:a60:f9f1:1602:ecff:fe68:f381%bond2:47520,
   /10.141.173.24:47520], discPort=47520, order=25, intOrder=17,
   lastExchangeTime=1574082959655, loc=true,
   ver=1.7.0#20160801-sha1:383273e3, isClient=false], topVer=25,
   nodeId8=3e9e1886, msg=null, type=NODE_JOINED, tstamp=1574077885508],

        crd=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=cc93a5f4-9ebb-4525-ab85-faf1fdbc0512, addrs=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo, 10.141.173.24, 10.141.180.83,
   10.142.225.62, 127.0.0.1, 2405:200:a60:f9f1:1602:ecff:fe68:f381%bond2],
   sockAddrs=[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo:47511, /127.0.0.1:47511,
   /10.141.173.24:47511, /10.142.225.62:47511,
   rocraappsl11.rjil.ril.com/10.141.180.83:47511,
   /2405:200:a60:f9f1:1602:ecff:fe68:f381%bond2:47511], discPort=47511,
   order=1, intOrder=1, lastExchangeTime=1574077885387, loc=false,
   ver=1.7.0#20160801-sha1:383273e3, isClient=false],
   exchId=GridDhtPartitionExchangeId [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion
   [topVer=25, minorTopVer=0], nodeId=3e9e1886, evt=NODE_JOINED],
   added=false, initFut=GridFutureAdapter [resFlag=0, res=null,
   startTime=1574077889490, endTime=0, ignoreInterrupts=false,
   state=INIT], init=false, topSnapshot=null, lastVer=null,
   partReleaseFut=null, affChangeMsg=null, skipPreload=false,
   clientOnlyExchange=false, initTs=1574077889500, centralizedAff=false,
   evtLatch=0, remaining=[9058a0e1-3273-4332-8e22-5fb684454a19,
   cc93a5f4-9ebb-4525-ab85-faf1fdbc0512,
   543ff498-148f-47d4-975b-c89d6615298b,
   33c47d08-a4f2-401f-98b2-0506c0166597,
   939e6462-4f17-455f-ad45-9d9e20d4543e,
   ca1b4061-60da-4d3f-8145-9aa12fca7ee6,
   12fa00f8-3512-4a84-b916-16d6f3534a9f,
   be853f0a-ec96-45eb-9d30-9e407606efac], 

        srvNodes=


        [TcpDiscoveryNode [id=cc93a5f4-9ebb-4525-ab85-faf1fdbc0512, addrs=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo, 10.141.173.24, 10.141.180.83,
   10.142.225.62, 127.0.0.1, 2405:200:a60:f9f1:1602:ecff:fe68:f381%bond2],
   sockAddrs=[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo:47511, /127.0.0.1:47511,
   /10.141.173.24:47511, /10.142.225.62:47511,
   rocraappsl11.rjil.ril.com/10.141.180.83:47511,
   /2405:200:a60:f9f1:1602:ecff:fe68:f381%bond2:47511], discPort=47511,
   order=1, intOrder=1, lastExchangeTime=1574077885387, loc=false,
   ver=1.7.0#20160801-sha1:383273e3, isClient=false], 

        TcpDiscoveryNode [id=543ff498-148f-47d4-975b-c89d6615298b, addrs=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo, 10.141.173.24, 10.141.180.83,
   10.142.225.62, 127.0.0.1, 2405:200:a60:f9f1:1602:ecff:fe68:f381%bond2],
   sockAddrs=[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo:47514,
   rocraappsl11.rjil.ril.com/10.141.180.83:47514, /127.0.0.1:47514,
   /2405:200:a60:f9f1:1602:ecff:fe68:f381%bond2:47514,
   /10.141.173.24:47514, /10.142.225.62:47514], discPort=47514, order=3,
   intOrder=3, lastExchangeTime=1574077885387, loc=false,
   ver=1.7.0#20160801-sha1:383273e3, isClient=false],

        TcpDiscoveryNode [id=12fa00f8-3512-4a84-b916-16d6f3534a9f, addrs=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo, 10.141.173.24, 10.141.180.83,
   10.142.225.62, 127.0.0.1, 2405:200:a60:f9f1:1602:ecff:fe68:f381%bond2],
   sockAddrs=[rocraappsl11.rjil.ril.com/10.141.180.83:47515,
   /2405:200:a60:f9f1:1602:ecff:fe68:f381%bond2:47515,
   /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo:47515, /127.0.0.1:47515, /10.141.173.24:47515,
   /10.142.225.62:47515], discPort=47515, order=4, intOrder=4,
   lastExchangeTime=1574077885397, loc=false,
   ver=1.7.0#20160801-sha1:383273e3, isClient=false], 

        TcpDiscoveryNode [id=9058a0e1-3273-4332-8e22-5fb684454a19, addrs=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo, 10.141.173.24, 10.141.180.83,
   10.142.225.62, 127.0.0.1, 2405:200:a60:f9f1:1602:ecff:fe68:f381%bond2],
   sockAddrs=[rocraappsl11.rjil.ril.com/10.141.180.83:47516,
   /2405:200:a60:f9f1:1602:ecff:fe68:f381%bond2:47516,
   /10.141.173.24:47516, /10.142.225.62:47516,
   /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo:47516, /127.0.0.1:47516], discPort=47516,
   order=5, intOrder=5, lastExchangeTime=1574077885397, loc=false,
   ver=1.7.0#20160801-sha1:383273e3, isClient=false], 

        TcpDiscoveryNode [id=be853f0a-ec96-45eb-9d30-9e407606efac, addrs=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo, 10.141.173.24, 10.141.180.83,
   10.142.225.62, 127.0.0.1, 2405:200:a60:f9f1:1602:ecff:fe68:f381%bond2],
   sockAddrs=[/2405:200:a60:f9f1:1602:ecff:fe68:f381%bond2:47517,
   /10.141.173.24:47517, /10.142.225.62:47517,
   /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo:47517,
   rocraappsl11.rjil.ril.com/10.141.180.83:47517, /127.0.0.1:47517],
   discPort=47517, order=6, intOrder=6, lastExchangeTime=1574077885397,
   loc=false, ver=1.7.0#20160801-sha1:383273e3, isClient=false],

        TcpDiscoveryNode [id=939e6462-4f17-455f-ad45-9d9e20d4543e, addrs=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo, 10.141.173.24, 10.141.180.83,
   10.142.225.62, 127.0.0.1, 2405:200:a60:f9f1:1602:ecff:fe68:f381%bond2],
   sockAddrs=[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo:47519, /127.0.0.1:47519,
   /10.141.173.24:47519, /10.142.225.62:47519,
   rocraappsl11.rjil.ril.com/10.141.180.83:47519,
   /2405:200:a60:f9f1:1602:ecff:fe68:f381%bond2:47519], discPort=47519,
   order=7, intOrder=7, lastExchangeTime=1574077885397, loc=false,
   ver=1.7.0#20160801-sha1:383273e3, isClient=false], 

        TcpDiscoveryNode [id=ca1b4061-60da-4d3f-8145-9aa12fca7ee6, addrs=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo, 10.141.173.24, 10.141.180.83,
   10.142.225.62, 127.0.0.1, 2405:200:a60:f9f1:1602:ecff:fe68:f381%bond2],
   sockAddrs=[/2405:200:a60:f9f1:1602:ecff:fe68:f381%bond2:47518,
   /10.141.173.24:47518, /10.142.225.62:47518,
   /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo:47518,
   rocraappsl11.rjil.ril.com/10.141.180.83:47518, /127.0.0.1:47518],
   discPort=47518, order=14, intOrder=11,
   lastExchangeTime=1574077885397, loc=false,
   ver=1.7.0#20160801-sha1:383273e3, isClient=false], 

        TcpDiscoveryNode [id=33c47d08-a4f2-401f-98b2-0506c0166597, addrs=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo, 10.141.173.24, 10.141.180.83,
   10.142.225.62, 127.0.0.1, 2405:200:a60:f9f1:1602:ecff:fe68:f381%bond2],
   sockAddrs=[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo:47512, /10.142.225.62:47512,
   /127.0.0.1:47512, rocraappsl11.rjil.ril.com/10.141.180.83:47512,
   /2405:200:a60:f9f1:1602:ecff:fe68:f381%bond2:47512,
   /10.141.173.24:47512], discPort=47512, order=18, intOrder=13,
   lastExchangeTime=1574077885397, loc=false,
   ver=1.7.0#20160801-sha1:383273e3, isClient=false], 

        TcpDiscoveryNode [id=3e9e1886-6e9c-491c-8145-e73c3f46ce8b, addrs=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo, 10.141.173.24, 10.141.180.83,
   10.142.225.62, 127.0.0.1, 2405:200:a60:f9f1:1602:ecff:fe68:f381%bond2],
   sockAddrs=[/10.142.225.62:47520, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo:47520,
   /127.0.0.1:47520, rocraappsl11.rjil.ril.com/10.141.180.83:47520,
   /2405:200:a60:f9f1:1602:ecff:fe68:f381%bond2:47520,
   /10.141.173.24:47520], discPort=47520, order=25, intOrder=17,
   lastExchangeTime=1574082959655, loc=true,
   ver=1.7.0#20160801-sha1:383273e3, isClient=false]],
   super=GridFutureAdapter [resFlag=0, res=null,
   startTime=1574077889490, endTime=0, ignoreInterrupts=false,
   state=INIT]]]
```

Comment: Can you share your configuration? It looks as though you've enabled some unusual options (shared memory for instance). And what does your topology look like? How many nodes/machines?

Comment: we have cluster of 5 machines and Ignite server is launched on each machine on IP address 172.0.0.1 and we are using local cache.

Answer (score 0):

I think this means you already have nodes started, but they are not operational/usable/fully alive so your new node can't complete the process of joining to them. You should be able to understand the reasoning by looking at their logs. Alternatively, just kill those nodes if they are not needed.

In this case it seems there are several:

```
WARN  9981874     90     2019-11-22 23:53:35     org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCachePartitionExchangeManager     Executor task launch worker-2     Still waiting for initial partition map exchange [fut=GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture [dummy=false, forcePreload=false, reassign=false, discoEvt=DiscoveryEvent [
    evtNode=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=c54ef27b-049e-466e-a594-3fffb01bd1e3, addrs=[10.141.180.69, 10.141.26.13, 10.142.225.122, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=[/10.141.26.13:47512, /127.0.0.1:47512, nvmbd2bgt130d00.rjil.ril.com/10.141.180.69:47512, /10.142.225.122:47512], discPort=47512, order=14, intOrder=9, lastExchangeTime=1574447015048, loc=true, ver=1.7.0#20160801-sha1:383273e3, isClient=false], topVer=14, nodeId8=c54ef27b, msg=null, type=NODE_JOINED, tstamp=1574446951740], 
    crd=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=81757f48-d3e7-466d-9058-8edc84496f4f, addrs=[10.141.180.69, 10.141.26.13, 10.142.225.122, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=[/127.0.0.1:47511, /10.141.26.13:47511, nvmbd2bgt130d00.rjil.ril.com/10.141.180.69:47511, /10.142.225.122:47511], discPort=47511, order=1, intOrder=1, lastExchangeTime=1574446951670, loc=false, ver=1.7.0#20160801-sha1:383273e3, isClient=false], exchId=GridDhtPartitionExchangeId [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=14, minorTopVer=0], nodeId=c54ef27b, evt=NODE_JOINED], added=false, initFut=GridFutureAdapter [resFlag=0, res=null, startTime=1574446955042, endTime=0, ignoreInterrupts=false, state=INIT], init=false, topSnapshot=null, lastVer=null, partReleaseFut=null, affChangeMsg=null, skipPreload=false, clientOnlyExchange=false, initTs=1574446955052, centralizedAff=false, evtLatch=0, remaining=[88ed2a8c-c0b5-4b93-b3e4-529d00d5b118, 81757f48-d3e7-466d-9058-8edc84496f4f, 6727f535-2e69-4520-a1e0-8b2a2380134d], 
srvNodes=[
    TcpDiscoveryNode [id=81757f48-d3e7-466d-9058-8edc84496f4f, addrs=[10.141.180.69, 10.141.26.13, 10.142.225.122, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=[/127.0.0.1:47511, /10.141.26.13:47511, nvmbd2bgt130d00.rjil.ril.com/10.141.180.69:47511, /10.142.225.122:47511], discPort=47511, order=1, intOrder=1, lastExchangeTime=1574446951670, loc=false, ver=1.7.0#20160801-sha1:383273e3, isClient=false], 
    TcpDiscoveryNode [id=6727f535-2e69-4520-a1e0-8b2a2380134d, addrs=[10.141.180.69, 10.141.26.13, 10.142.225.122, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=[/10.142.225.122:47515, /127.0.0.1:47515, /10.141.26.13:47515, nvmbd2bgt130d00.rjil.ril.com/10.141.180.69:47515], discPort=47515, order=5, intOrder=4, lastExchangeTime=1574446951670, loc=false, ver=1.7.0#20160801-sha1:383273e3, isClient=false], 
    TcpDiscoveryNode [id=88ed2a8c-c0b5-4b93-b3e4-529d00d5b118, addrs=[10.141.180.69, 10.141.26.13, 10.142.225.122, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=[/10.142.225.122:47516, /10.141.26.13:47516, /127.0.0.1:47516, nvmbd2bgt130d00.rjil.ril.com/10.141.180.69:47516], discPort=47516, order=8, intOrder=6, lastExchangeTime=1574446951670, loc=false, ver=1.7.0#20160801-sha1:383273e3, isClient=false], 
    TcpDiscoveryNode [id=c54ef27b-049e-466e-a594-3fffb01bd1e3, addrs=[10.141.180.69, 10.141.26.13, 10.142.225.122, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=[/10.141.26.13:47512, /127.0.0.1:47512, nvmbd2bgt130d00.rjil.ril.com/10.141.180.69:47512, /10.142.225.122:47512], discPort=47512, order=14, intOrder=9, lastExchangeTime=1574447015048, loc=true, ver=1.7.0#20160801-sha1:383273e3, isClient=false]], super=GridFutureAdapter [resFlag=0, res=null, startTime=1574446955042, endTime=0, ignoreInterrupts=false, state=INIT]]]
```

Comment: You mean, one grid is already running and it is trying to start another one.

Comment: It is trying to join an existing grid.

Comment: Is there any way to get more details , like which Grid  is it  trying to join? IP Address of Grid or Grid Name , anything which can give any clue.